# Существует ли четкое правило обособления существительных в косвенных падежах с предлогами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Уважаемые форумчане, скажите, пожалуйста, существует ли четкое правило обособления обстоятельственных оборотов, выраженных существительными в косвенных падежах с предлогами? Насколько мне известно, их обособление преимущественно факультативно, за исключением расположения оборота между подлежащим и сказуемым (обособляется); всегда обособляются обстоятельства уступки. Вроде бы всё, то есть правило довольно размытое или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне  правило не кажется размытым.

> Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными
>
> 1. Всегда обособляются обстоятельства **уступки**, выраженные существительными с предлогами **несмотря на, невзирая на**. **Такие
>      обороты можно заменить на придаточные предложения уступки с союзом
>      хотя.**
>
> Ср.: *Несмотря на дождливое лето, урожай выдался отличный (Почивалин).
>   – Хотя лето было дождливым, урожай выдался отличный; Невзирая на
>   сильный обстрел, Федюнинский поднялся на свой наблюдательный пункт. –
>   Хотя обстрел был сильным, Федюнинский поднялся на свой наблюдательный
>   пункт.*
>
> 2. Могут обособляться обстоятельства:
>
> • **причины** с предлогами и предложными сочетаниями **благодаря,
>   вследствие, ввиду, за неимением, за отсутствием, согласно, в силу, в
>   связи с, по причине, по случаю и др**. (**можно заменить придаточным
>   предложением с союзом так как).**
>
> Ср.: *Савельич, согласно с мнением ямщика, советовал воротиться. – Так
>   как Савельич был согласен с мнением ямщика, он советовал воротиться;
>   Детям, по причине малолетства, не определили никаких должностей
>   (Тургенев). – Так как дети были маленькими, им не определили никаких
>   должностей;*
>
> • **уступки с предлогами вопреки, при** (**можно заменить придаточным
>   предложением с союзом хотя).**
>
> Ср.: *Жизнь его, при всей тяжести его положения, шла легче, стройнее,
>   нежели жизнь Анатоля (Герцен). – Хотя положение было тяжёлым, жизнь
>   его шла легче, стройнее, нежели жизнь Анатоля; Вопреки его указаниям,
>   корабли вывели в море ранним утром (Федосеев). – Хотя он дал указания,
>   корабли вывели в море ранним утром.*
>
> • **условия с предлогами и предложными сочетаниями при наличии, при
>   отсутствии, в случае и др.** (**можно заменить придаточным
>   предложением с союзом если)**.
>
> Ср.: *Рабочие, в случае отказа, решили объявить забастовку. – Если
>   рабочим будет отказано, они решили объявить забастовку;*
>
> • **цели с предлогами и предложными сочетаниями во избежание** (можно
>   заменить придаточным предложением с союзом чтобы).
>
> Ср.: *Деньги, во избежание задержки, переведите телеграфом. – Чтобы
>   избежать задержки, деньги переведите телеграфом;*
>
> • **сравнения с союзом подобно**.
>
> Ср.: *Николай Петрович родился на юге России, подобно старшему брату
>   Павлу (Тургенев).
>
> Кроме того, **обособленные обороты обычно распространены**, то есть
>   содержат существительное с зависимыми словами:
>
> *Благодаря хорошей погоде и особенно праздничному дню, наша улица снова оживилась.*
>
> Как правило, **не обособляются указанные обороты в конце
>   предложения**. Например: *Заключенные, по приказу смотрителя,
>   направились в камеры. – Заключенные пошли в камеры по приказу
>   смотрителя.*
>
> **При небольшой распространенности таких членов предложения возможны варианты** в их пунктуационном оформлении, диктуемые **разным порядком
>   слов.**
>
> Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями
>   **обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым:** разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению
>   оборотов. То же **при разрыве естественной связи управляющего и
>   управляемого слов**. В других позициях, особенно в
>   малораспространенных предложениях, такие обороты не осложняют
>   предложение особыми выделительными интонациями и могут не обособляться
>   (без специального на то задания).
>
> Например: *Во избежание утечки газа отключен кран.  – Отключен, во
>   избежание утечки газа, кран; Он сделал это в силу привычки.  – Он, в
>   силу привычки, сделал это; Согласно приказу группа расформирована.  –
>   Группа, согласно приказу, расформирована; За отсутствием состава
>   преступления дело прекращено.  – Дело, за отсутствием состава
>   преступления, прекращено.*
>
> 3. **Обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными, без предлогов или с иными предлогами, обособляются только в том случае,
>      если приобретают дополнительную смысловую нагрузку, имеют
>      пояснительное значение или совмещают несколько обстоятельственных
>      значений (временное и причинное, временное и уступительное и др.).**
>
> Например: *Петя, после полученного им решительного отказа, ушёл в свою
>   комнату (Л. Толстой). В данном случае обстоятельство совмещает
>   значения времени и причины (когда ушёл? и почему ушёл?). Обратите
>   внимание на то, что оборот выражен существительным с зависимыми
>   словами и расположен между подлежащим и сказуемым.*

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/721-252_obosoblenie_obstoyatelstv.html